# A doubt in the proof of Combinatorial nullstellensatz

Tags: extremal-combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics

**(Combinatorial Nullstellensatz I)**  Let $f\in \mathbb{F[x_1,x_2\ldots x_n]}$, and let $S_1,S_2\ldots S_n$ be non empty subsets of $\mathbb{F}$. If $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in S_1\times S_2\times \ldots S_n$, then there are polynomials $h_1,h_2\ldots h_n\in \mathbb{F[x_1,x_2\ldots x_n]}$ such that $deg(h_i)\le deg(f)-|S_i|$ and $f(x_1,x_2\ldots x_n)=\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}h_i(x_1,x_2\ldots x_n)\prod\limits_{s\in S_i}(x_i-s)$.

First please see the following line of proofs. I have a doubt in the last line.

Assume that $g_i(x_i)=\prod\limits_{s\in S_i}(x_i-s)$ for $i=1,2\cdots n$. Now if $x_i\in S_i$ then $g_i(x_i)=0$, that is $x_i^{|S_i|}=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{|S_i|-1}a_{ij}x_i^j$ for $1\le i \le n$.

For $1\le i \le n$, in the polynomial $f$ every occurrences of $x_i^k$ where $k\ge |S_i|$ are replaced by linear combination of  smaller power of $x_i$ by using the relation $x_i^{|S_i|}=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{|S_i|-1}a_{ij}x_i^j$. This process will continue until and unless we do not get the power of $x_i$ less than $|S_i|$ for $1\le i \le n$. Let the resultant polynomial be $f'$. Now there exist polynomials $h_i(x_1,x_2\ldots x_n)$ for $1\le i \le n$ such that $f-f'=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}h_i(x_1,x_2,\ldots x_n)g_i(x_i)$.

Question: How do I get the polynomials $h_i(x_1,x_2\ldots x_n)$ for $1\le i \le n$?

Comment: You have obtained $f'$ from $f$ by a multi-step procedure; each step consisted in replacing a power of $x_i$ by a linear combination of smaller powers. Due to the definition of this linear combination, you can easily check that each step merely subtracts a multiple of $g_i\left(x_i\right)$ from the polynomial. Thus, the resulting polynomial $f'$ at the end of the process differs from $f$ by a sum of multiples of $g_i\left(x_i\right)$. This is exactly the same argument as for the classical fact that polynomials can be divided with remainder (except that we now have many variables).

Comment: May I get an example on two or one variable?

Comment: May I get an example on two or one variable? I am trying to express $f(x)=(x^3+x+1)(x^3+x^2+1)$ by the power of $x$ less than $4$ with help of substitution $x^4=x^3+1$. My final polynomial should be $f-f'=h(x)(x^4-x^3-1)$. I am trying like this. $f(x)=x^6+x^5+x^4+g'(x)$ where deg(g'(x)) is less than $4$. $f'(x)=(x^2+x+1)(x^3+1)+g'(x)$. But I am not getting the form $f(x)-f'(x)=h(x)(x^4-x^3-1)$